# Map Reduce In Java

Tags: java

So I need to accomplish the following:
A game company receives data from its players at the end of every hour. Each time a player buys something in the game, a new row is generated inside a CSV file with the following format:

```
Input:
fileContent: "2017-04-01, 11:25, 2; 2017-04-02, 11:30, 8; 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9; 2017-04-01, 11:42, 700; 2017-04-01, 11:00, 25; 2017-04-02, 14:56, 23; 2017-04-02, 18:20, 57; 2017-04-03, 14:30, 8; 2017-04-03, 14:42, 12"
date: "2017-04-01"
hour: 11
Expected Output:
727
Where the first value is the date, the second one the time and the third one the amount of coins spent.
```

Being given the content of the file, a certain date and an hour (just the hour, without minutes), the company wants to know how much coins were spent during that hour.
    I tried to accomplish this as follows:

```
int MapReduceProblem(String fileContent, String date, int hour) {
    int coins;
    coins = 0;
    if(fileContent.contains(";")){
        String[] fileLines = fileContent.split("\\;");
        for(int i = 0; i <= fileLines.length; i++){
          String[] lineData = fileLines[i].split("\\,");
          String[] hourSplit = lineData[1].split("\\:");
          int fileHour = Integer.parseInt(hourSplit[0]);
            if(fileHour == hour){
                int coin = Integer.parseInt(lineData[2]);
                coins += coin;
            }
        }
        return coins;
    }
    else{
        String[] lineData = fileContent.split("\\,");
        String[] hourSplit = lineData[1].split("\\:");
        int fileHour = Integer.parseInt(lineData[0]);
            if(fileHour == hour){
                int coin = Integer.parseInt(hourSplit[2]);
                coins += coin;
            }
         return coins;
    }

}
```

I get errors from the main:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at myCode._invoke(file.java on line ?)
    at myCode.main(file.java on line ?)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at myCode._invoke(file.java on line ?)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-04-04"
```

The problem is that I don't have access to the main (it's a practice problem and this is the reason I cannot access the main).
   I am new to java so if you can try and explain to me the reason why I failed it would be most appreciated.
   Thank you all for your time!

Comment: You're trying to parse `2017-04-04` as a number, but it's not a number.

Comment: You also need to split by `-` somewhere.

Comment: @Socowi Maybe just parse it as a date instead.

Comment: Method names are lowerCamelCase in Java

Comment: The method name is predefined by the site on which I am practicing...the params too. I only wrote the code inside of it.